# Removing user login credentials from session when user logout in spring-security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to Spring and Spring-Security. I have been going through the tutorials
[here](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/16/login-form-based-spring-3-security-example/)

The user are not allowed to hit add employee page without login. So if you hit add employee page, you will be directed to the login page and when login succeeded you are directed to the add employee page automatically.

But once the user logged in add employee link can be accessed even after the user logs out. It can be accessed even after the server is restarted, I had to close the browser window for the login credentials to be destroyed.

It works fine when when I keep the logout url as "j_spring_security_logout" which I dont want to use. I want to use custom feild names and urls, is it possible?

This is how my spring-security.xml looks

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/accessdenied" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/list"
        authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true"
        delete-cookies="true" />
</http>
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="hasif" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

This is how my LoginController looks

```java
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login() {     
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logout(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        session.invalidate();
        return "logout";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/accessdenied", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String accessdenied() {
        return "accessdenied";
    }
}
```

Comment: In your configuration you are only specifying the `logout-succes-url` you aren't speficing the `logout-url`. `logout-succes-url` is the URL you are send to after logout was succesful.

Comment: @M.Deinum that was it. I forgot to put logout-url. But is there any way to change textbox name of username and password from their default names like j_username and j_password?

Comment: How about specifing the `username-parameter` and `password-parameter` on the `form-login` tag... This is all explained in the documentation!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your configuration is wrong, you must specify the `logout-url` attribute and not the `logout-success-url`. The latter is the url you are send to after logout has been successful.

```
<logout logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="true" />
```

`delete-cookies` takes a comma separated string with names of cookies to delete, I doubt you have a cookie named `true` and the session is invalidated by default. So basically the following gives the same result.

```
<logout logout-url="/logout" />
```

If you want to change the name of the parameter to use for specifying the username/password add respectively the `username-parameter` and `password-parameter` on the `form-login` element.

```
<form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/list" authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied" username-parameter="my-username-param" password-parameter="my-password-param"/>
```

For an explanation of the namespaces I suggest a read of [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-web).

Answer (score 0):

First `Why do you want to do manually` when Spring provide such a good security feature.

No doubt you can handle it by your self. For this you have to just `invalidate` the current session when user click on Log out button or link. There is method available `HttpSession#invalidate()` which can solve your problem.

Comment: I did tried invalidating the session from the Controller, but has no effect.

I am not changing any security features, I just want to use custom url and field names. I am sure there should be some way for doing it. I just want to find out.

Comment: @Hasif Do you have Remember-Me configured anywhere else?

Comment: @VimalBera it works when I keep logout url as "j_spring_security_logout", But I would like to use "logout" instead.

Comment: Are you sure your logout controller is called?